# Android Studio 0.3.5 does not recognise test directory

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I have a standard folders structure just like Android Studio creates for a new project. In my `build.gradle` I wrote:

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot('scr/test')
}
```

Nonetheless the dir doesn't recognised as Test Root, it is not green. Although `./gradlew testDebug` runs test from that folder. Is it a bug in Android Studio? My settings?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly the code does, but comparing it with your directory structure, in a first glance I'm noticing the difference in directory name.

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')   //its src, not scr
}
```

Perhaps that's causing the problem  :)

Comment: oh man, that's why sometimes you need another pair of eyes :) Thanks.

Comment: it happens with everyone  :)